# Converting C++ builder 6 project to C++ builder 2010

Tags: c++, rsa, c++builder, encryption

I have a simple project that's written in c++ builder 6. It's about encryption RSA algorithm.
Wanted to convert to c++ builder 2010 but it gives errors

e.g. source code of main project

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "UTForm.h"
#include "UTRSA.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
randomize();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TRSA a(Edit4->Text.ToInt());

char* tmp = a.KeyModul;
Edit1->Text = AnsiString(tmp);
tmp = a.OpenKey;
Edit2->Text = AnsiString(tmp);
tmp = a.SecretKey;
Edit3->Text = AnsiString(tmp);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TNumber n(Edit1->Text.c_str());
TNumber e(Edit2->Text.c_str());
TNumber d(Edit3->Text.c_str());

THexString text;
text.AsCharString = Edit5->Text;

if (Edit3->Text != "")
  {
  TRSA a(n,e,d,Edit4->Text.ToInt());
  a.PlainText = text;
  Edit6->Text = a.CryptedText.AsHexString;
  }
else
  {
  TRSA a(n,e,Edit4->Text.ToInt());
  a.PlainText = text;
  Edit6->Text = a.CryptedText.AsHexString;
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
TNumber n(Edit1->Text.c_str());
TNumber e(Edit2->Text.c_str());
TNumber d(Edit3->Text.c_str());

THexString text;
text.AsHexString = Edit6->Text;

if (Edit3->Text != "")
  {
  TRSA a(n,e,d,Edit4->Text.ToInt());
  a.CryptedText = text;
  Edit8->Text = a.PlainText.AsCharString;
  }
else
  {
  TRSA a(n,e,Edit4->Text.ToInt());
  a.CryptedText = text;
  Edit8->Text = a.PlainText.AsCharString;
  }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

errors are:

```
Build
  Checking project dependencies...
  Compiling RSA.cbproj (Debug configuration)
  [BCC32 Warning] UTHexString.cpp(92): W8012 Comparing signed and unsigned values
  [BCC32 Warning] UTHexString.cpp(92): W8012 Comparing signed and unsigned values
  [BCC32 Warning] UTForm.cpp(29): W8057 Parameter 'Sender' is never used
  [BCC32 Error] UTForm.cpp(33): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TNumber::TNumber(wchar_t *)'
  [BCC32 Error] UTForm.cpp(34): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TNumber::TNumber(wchar_t *)'
  [BCC32 Error] UTForm.cpp(35): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TNumber::TNumber(wchar_t *)'
  [BCC32 Warning] UTForm.cpp(52): W8057 Parameter 'Sender' is never used
  [BCC32 Error] UTForm.cpp(57): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TNumber::TNumber(wchar_t *)'
  [BCC32 Error] UTForm.cpp(58): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TNumber::TNumber(wchar_t *)'
  [BCC32 Error] UTForm.cpp(59): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TNumber::TNumber(wchar_t *)'
  [BCC32 Warning] UTForm.cpp(76): W8057 Parameter 'Sender' is never used
  Failed
  Elapsed time: 00:00:01.5
Project Import
  Upgrading project "D:\SOFTS\DELPHI and C++ Builder 2009\Cryptography\RSA\RSA\RSA.bpr"
    Reading "D:\SOFTS\DELPHI and C++ Builder 2009\Cryptography\RSA\RSA\RSA.bpr"
    Upgraded to "D:\SOFTS\DELPHI and C++ Builder 2009\Cryptography\RSA\RSA\RSA.cbproj"
```

I think C++ Builder 2010 has default unicode support that's why or I am wrong ?
When I looked at the TNumber constructor it has the following:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef UTNumberH
#define UTNumberH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

class TNumber
{
private:
       TNumber   multdigit(int) const;
       TNumber   mult10(int) const;

       char     *vlstr;                          
       int       vlen;                           
       int       vlsign;                         

public:

                 TNumber(const char* = NULL);    
                 TNumber(int);                   
                 TNumber(const TNumber &);       
                ~TNumber();                      

                 operator int() const;
                 operator long() const;
                 operator double() const;
                 operator char*() const;

  const TNumber& operator=(const TNumber&);

     TNumber operator - () const;
     TNumber operator ++ ();
     TNumber operator ++ (int);
     TNumber operator -- ();
     TNumber operator -- (int);

         TNumber operator += (const TNumber &);
     TNumber operator -= (const TNumber &);
     TNumber operator *= (const TNumber &);
     TNumber operator /= (const TNumber &);
     TNumber operator %= (const TNumber &);

  friend TNumber operator + (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend TNumber operator - (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend TNumber operator * (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend TNumber operator / (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend TNumber operator % (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);

  friend int     operator == (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend int     operator != (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend int     operator < (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend int     operator <= (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend int     operator > (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend int     operator >= (const TNumber &, const TNumber &);

         char*   strrev(char *s) const;
  friend TNumber abs(const TNumber &);
  friend TNumber sqrt(const TNumber &);
  friend TNumber pow(const TNumber &, const TNumber &);
  friend double  div(const TNumber &, const TNumber &);

  friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const TNumber &);
  friend istream & operator >> (istream &, TNumber &);

  friend TNumber rnd(const TNumber& from, const TNumber& to);
};

const TNumber zero = TNumber("0");
const TNumber one  = TNumber("1");
const TNumber two  = TNumber("2");

TNumber eae(TNumber u, TNumber v);             

#endif
```

Where am I wrong ?

In addition find the c++ builder 6 project attached !

Comment: Yes, TNumber only has a TNumber(const char*) constructor, not a TNumber(const wchar_t*) constructor.  Improve TNumber or give up on Unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. `UnicodeString` is what most strings are by default in 2010. Since the `Text` property is most likely one of these, the safest way to make things compile would be to convert back using something like the following:

```
TNumber n( AnsiString( Edit1->Text ).c_str() );
```

**Update:**

Based off comments I'll clarify the answer a bit. The answer is assuming that the code is still only expecting ANSi data. Otherwise, a better solution, as David M. indicated, is to change the underlying TNumber class to handle UnicodeString (i.e. wchar_t).

Comment: Re Scott's answer: "Safest" - don't forget Unicode to ANSI conversions are lossy.  This will get you compiling but is bad advice overall if you will ever, ever, maybe, perhaps, tiny chance ever have a non-ANSI character used by one of your users and your program.  A better solution in the long term would be to make TNumber handle a wchar_t* or UnicodeString constructor.  You can make use of the VCL string / number conversion routines here (eg StrToInt, StrToFloat.)

Comment: I've tried to add TNumber (wchar_t * ) constructor but it didn't work at all !

Comment: @Scott Saad. You are right I did what you told and it's ok now with TNumber but it gives other errors like in log10 (math.h) function. Could you please, look over my project that I have attached and correct the errors? I would be very gratefull for you ! Thanks in advance! Find my project below in the following link http://depositfiles.com/files/wi219076b

Comment: Please send me to suhrob87@gmail.com then if you get it done! Thanks!

Comment: Update the answer with @david-m's suggestions.

Comment: @suhrob-samiev, I won't be able to dig through the project files for you. However, if you would like to post the new errors you are getting I'm sure we can attempt to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

"Parameter 'Sender' is never used".

- Project  => Options
- С++ Compiler => Warnings
- "Enable selected Warnings"
- "8056 Parameter is newer used" - False.